# What prompted Bose's move to Dhaka University in 1921?

Tags: physics, social-context

Satyendra Nath Bose who discovered boson statistics and is credited by Einstein for also discovering the Bose-Einstein condensate was born in Calcutta, was educated there at Presidency College and then at the University of Calcutta. After graduating he taught there at Rajbazar Science College.

In 1921 he moved to the newly founded Dhaka university as a Reader at the Physics Department helping to set up 'whole new departments including laboratories' and teaching both undergraduate and graduate courses. He worked mainly in theoretical physics and X-Ray crystallography. It's whilst there he published his famous paper in 1924, *Plancks Law and the Light Quantum Hypothesis*, a copy of which he had sent to Einstein and who responded enthusiastically.

What prompted his move to a newly founded university with, presumably, no reputation to speak of?